# Cocos2d-x problems with CCCallback with arguments

Tags: android, c++, callback, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to animate  a Sprite with CCSequence and I need to pass argument to the callback, but when I do it I get

> signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000021

Here is my code:

```
void Board::createExplotion(CCPoint boardPosition){
    Mineral* mineralToAnimate = this->boardPieces[(unsigned char) boardPosition.y][(unsigned char) boardPosition.x];
    CCArray* params = CCArray::create(mineralToAnimate, NULL);

    params->retain();

    CCSequence* s1 = CCSequence::create(
                        CCScaleTo::create(0.5f, SELECTED_SCALE),
                        CCScaleTo::create(0.25f, SELECTED_SCALE + 0.1),
                        CCCallFuncO::create(this, callfuncO_selector(Board::test), params )
                        //CCCallFunc::create(this, callfunc_selector(Board::test))
                    );

        mineralToAnimate->runAction(s1);
    }

void Board::test(CCNode* sender, CCObject* data){ ... }
```

I tried the same code without arguments and it works.

I'm working with eclipse and the debugger does not help a lot, or at least I don't know how, and the adb logcat show this:

Build fingerprint:

> 'samsung/espressowifixx/espressowifi:4.1.1/JRO03C/P3110XXCLK7:user/release-keys'
>   pid: 4931, tid: 4946, name: Thread-32873  >>> org.cocos2dx.hellocpp
>   <<< signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000021
>   Stack frame #00  pc 00099ed2 
>   /data/data/org.cocos2dx.hellocpp/lib/libhellocpp.so
>   (cocos2d::CCSequence::initWithTwoActions(cocos2d::CCFiniteTimeAction*,
>   cocos2d::CCFiniteTimeAction*)+93) Stack frame #01  pc 00099fc9 
>   /data/data/org.cocos2dx.hellocpp/lib/libhellocpp.so
>   (cocos2d::CCSequence::createWithTwoActions(cocos2d::CCFiniteTimeAction*,
>   cocos2d::CCFiniteTimeAction*)+44) Stack frame #02  pc 0009a059 
>   /data/data/org.cocos2dx.hellocpp/lib/libhellocpp.so
>   (cocos2d::CCSequence::createWithVariableList(cocos2d::CCFiniteTimeAction*,
>   std::__va_list)+22) Stack frame #03  pc 0009a083 
>   /data/data/org.cocos2dx.hellocpp/lib/libhellocpp.so
>   (cocos2d::CCSequence::create(cocos2d::CCFiniteTimeAction*, ...)+10)
>   Stack frame #04  pc 0008ea5d 
>   /data/data/org.cocos2dx.hellocpp/lib/libhellocpp.so
>   (Board::createExplotion(cocos2d::CCPoint)+100)

Thanks.

Comment: You have missed NULL at the end.
CCSequence::create(<object1>, <object2>, NULL)
But m not sure that is making the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send data with action callback then you have to use Node and Data selector instead of an Object selector. Therefore change the line :

```
CCCallFuncO::create(this, callfuncO_selector(Board::test), params )
```

to

```
CCCallFuncND::create(this, callfuncND_selector(Board::test), params )
```

Comment: But if i want to send a CCObject shouldn't I use callfuncO?

Comment: In callback function `Board::test` if you need to know which object has executed it, then you can use `callfuncO_selector`

Comment: Ok, it works but I have missed also NULL at the end.